# Serving arbitrary subdomains using apache2, mod_wsgi and django

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, django, mod-wsgi, subdomain

I'm attempting to setup a django development server using a sandbox approach.  The specific technologies in place are apache2, mod_wsgi and django.

I'd like to use subdomains formatted as: {project}-{user}.domain.com.

I'd like that subdomain to point here: /home/{user}/{project}/application/django.wsgi.

Is this possible to setup via Virtual Hosts to work automatically, and if so, what would such a Virtual Host file look like?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use mod_rewrite to add %{SERVERNAME} to the path to django.wsgi.

Have a look at this excellent document: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/mass.html#simple.rewrite